# Generating product variants in Ruby

Tags: ruby

Based on the sample variants, I need to get all combinations of all variants. In the example I have 3x3x2=18 variants.

```rb
## SAMPLE VARIANTS
sizes = ['small', 'medium', 'large']
colors = ['red', 'green', 'blue']
materials = ['cotton', 'linen']

## ITERATE TO ALL VARIANTS
titles = []
sizes.each do |size|
  colors.each do |color|
    materials.each do |material|
      ## PUT THE VARIANT IN THE NEW ARRAY
      titles.push("#{size} - #{color} - #{material}")
    end
  end
end

puts titles.inspect
```

Is my nested each loop preferred or there is some better implementation for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Frozen string literals

Immutable data structures and purely functional code are always preferred, unless mutability and side-effects are required for clarity or performance. In Ruby, strings are always mutable, but there is a [magic comment](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/8976) you can add to your files (also available as a command-line option for the Ruby engine), which will automatically make all literal strings immutable:

```rb
# frozen_string_literal: true
```

It is generally preferred to add this comment to all your files.

## Word array "percent" literals

Ruby has [special array literals for arrays of single-word strings](https://ruby-doc.org/core/doc/syntax/literals_rdoc.html#label-Percent+Strings) that can make your code easier to read by reducing the amount of "syntax fluff" around the actual content.

The literal starts with the sigils `%w` or `%W` (think "word" or "witespace-separated"). `%w` behaves like a single-quoted string, i.e. does not perform interpolation and supports no escape characters other than `\'` and `\\`. `%W` behaves like a double-quoted string.

So, the beginning of your script could look like this:

```ruby
# frozen_string_literal: true

## SAMPLE VARIANTS
sizes = %w[small medium large]
colors = %w[red green blue]
materials = %w[cotton linen]
```

As with all percent literals, you can freely choose the delimiter you want to use such that the delimiter does not occur inside the literal. For example, you can use `|` as the delimiter, `,`, `@` anything you want:

```ruby
sizes = %w@small medium large@
colors = %w@red green blue@
materials = %w@cotton linen@
```

The first character after the `w` determines the delimiter. Delimiters come in two variants: paired and unpaired. With an unpaired delimiter, the same character ends the literal, as in the second example. With a paired delimiter, the corresponding closing delimiter ends the literal, e.g. when you start with `<`, you close with `>`, etc. See the first example.

## Linting

You should run some sort of linter or static analyzer on your code. [Rubocop](https://www.rubocop.org/) is a popular one, but there are others.

Rubocop was able to detect all of the style improvements I pointed out above, and also was able to autocorrect all of the ones I listed.

I have set up my editor such that it automatically runs Rubocop with auto-fix as soon as I hit "save".

Here's what the result of the auto-fix looks like:

```ruby
# frozen_string_literal: true

## SAMPLE VARIANTS
sizes = %w[small medium large]
colors = %w[red green blue]
materials = %w[cotton linen]

## ITERATE TO ALL VARIANTS
titles = []
sizes.each do |size|
  colors.each do |color|
    materials.each do |material|
      ## PUT THE VARIANT IN THE NEW ARRAY
      titles.push("#{size} - #{color} - #{material}")
    end
  end
end

puts titles.inspect
```

## `puts foo.inspect`

[`Kernel#p`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-p) is the preferred debugging method. It does the same thing, but is more idiomatic, and is specifically designed for quick debugging (hence the one-character name).

So, the last line can simply be

```ruby
p titles
```

Also, [`Kernel#puts`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-puts) returns `nil`, but `Kernel#p` returns its argument(s), so you can quickly chuck it into a long chain of expressions without changing the result.

## Vertical whitespace

Your code could use some vertical whitespace to give the code more room to breathe. I would suggest at least separating the initialization at the beginning of the loop:

```ruby
titles = []

sizes.each do |size|
  colors.each do |color|
    materials.each do |material|
      ## PUT THE VARIANT IN THE NEW ARRAY
      titles.push("#{size} - #{color} - #{material}")
    end
  end
end
```

## The "shovel" operator `<<`

[`Array#push`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-push) is not idiomatic. More precisely, it is *only* idiomatic if you are using the array as a *stack*, then you would use `Array#push` and [`Array#pop`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-pop), since those are the standard names for the stack operations.

The idiomatic way of appending something to something else is the shovel operator, in this case [`Array#<<`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-3C-3C), so that should be

```ruby
titles << "#{size} - #{color} - #{material}"
```

## Iterators

In Ruby, it is idiomatic to use high-level iterators. In your code, you are already using iterators instead of loops, so that is good. However, [`each`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-each) is really the lowest-level of all the iterators. It is essentially equivalent to a `FOREACH-OF` loop. It has no higher-level semantics, and it relies on mutation and side-effects.

Whenever you have the pattern of "Initialize a result, loop over a collection appending to the result, return result", that is a [*fold*](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_(higher-order_function)). There are two implementations of *fold* in the Ruby core library, [`inject`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject) and [`each_with_object`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object). `inject` is the more functional one, `each_with_object` is the more imperative one. So, for now, we will use `each_with_object` here, since the code is still pretty imperative, and that makes the relationship between the old and new code more clear.

As a general transformation,

```ruby
accumulator = some_initial_value

collection.each do |element|
  accumulator = do_something_with(accumulator, element)
end
```

becomes

```ruby
accumulator = collection.inject(some_initial_value) do |accumulator, element|
  do_something_with(accumulator, element)
end
```

or

```ruby
collection.each_with_object(some_initial_value) do |element, accumulator|
  do_something_with(accumulator, element)
end
```

In your case, it would look like this:

```ruby
titles = []

sizes.each do |size|
  colors.each do |color|
    materials.each do |material|
      ## PUT THE VARIANT IN THE NEW ARRAY
      titles << "#{size} - #{color} - #{material}"
    end
  end
end
```

becomes

```ruby
titles = []

sizes.each_with_object(titles) do |size, titles|
  colors.each_with_object(titles) do |color, titles|
    materials.each_with_object(titles) do |material, titles|
      ## PUT THE VARIANT IN THE NEW ARRAY
      titles << "#{size} - #{color} - #{material}"
    end
  end
end
```

Granted, this doesn't buy us much, actually the opposite. It starts to look slightly different though, when we move to a purely functional version without side-effects and mutation using `Enumerable#inject`:

```ruby
titles = sizes.inject([]) do |acc, size|
  colors.inject(acc) do |acc, color|
    materials.inject(acc) do |acc, material|
      ## PUT THE VARIANT IN THE NEW ARRAY
      acc + ["#{size} - #{color} - #{material}"]
    end
  end
end
```

## Linter, revisited

Rubocop actually complains about my use of *shadowing* the outer `acc` with the inner `acc`.

I disagree. You should not be afraid to disable or re-configure rules in your linter to fit your style.

However, note that programming is a team sport. If you are *modifying* code, adopt the existing style. If you are part of a team, adopt the team's style. If you write open source code, adopt the project's style. If you start your own project, adopt the community's style (do *not* create your own style for your project, until your project is big and successful enough to have its own independent community).

## Excursion: Generality of *fold* (`inject` / `each_with_object`)

When I wrote above that you can rewrite this iteration with `inject` or `each_with_object`, that was actually a tautological statement. I didn't even have to read the code to make this statement.

It turns out that *fold* is "general". [*Every* iteration over a collection can be expressed using *fold*](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_(higher-order_function)#Universality). This means, if we were to delete *every method* from `Enumerable`, except `inject`, then we could re-implement the entire `Enumerable` module again, using nothing but `inject`. As long as we have `inject`, we can do anything.

## Iterators, take 2

So, what we did until now was replace the low-level iterator with a higher-level iterator.

However, we are still not done. What we are now doing is we take each three elements from our three collections, concatenating them, and putting it into a new collection. So, really, what we are doing is *transforming* each element (or triple of elements), or "mapping" each element to a new element.

This is called [*map*](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_(higher-order_function)) and is also available in Ruby as [`Enumerable#map`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-map).

So, finally, our code looks like this:

```ruby
titles = sizes.map do |size|
  colors.map do |color|
    materials.map do | material|
      "#{size} - #{color} - #{material}"
    end
  end
end
```

This result is actually not quite right: we get a triply-nested array, because we have a triply-nested `Enumerable#map`.

We could [`Array#flatten`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-flatten) the result, but there is a better way: [`Enumerable#flat_map`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-flat_map):

```ruby
titles = sizes.flat_map do |size|
  colors.flat_map do |color|
    materials.map do | material|
      "#{size} - #{color} - #{material}"
    end
  end
end
```

What we did here, was to replace the *general* high-level iterator *fold* (which can do *anything*) with a more restricted, more specialized high-level iterator *map*. By using a more specialized iterator, we are able to better convey our semantics to the reader. Instead of thinking "Okay, so here we have an accumulator, and an element, and we do something with the element, and then append it to the accumulator … ah, I see, we are transforming each element", the reader just sees `map` and instantly *knows* that `map` transforms the elements.

## Array methods

There is not much we can improve in the code by using iterators. However, there are many more methods in both the [`Enumerable` mixin](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html) and the [`Array` class](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html).

So, let's take a step back and think about what we are *actually* doing here: we are constructing the [*Cartesian Product*](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) of the three arrays. And perhaps not surprisingly, there already is a method that computes a product of arrays, creatively named [`Array#product`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-product):

```ruby
titles = sizes.product(colors, materials).map do |size, color, material|
  "#{size} - #{color} - #{material}"
end
```

## `Array#join`

As a last improvement, let's look at what the block is doing: it is "joining" the three variants together. And again, there is already a method which does that: [`Array#join`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-join):

```ruby
titles = sizes.product(colors, materials).map do |variant|
  variant.join(' - ')
end
```

## Final result

So, in the end, the entire thing looks something like this:

```ruby
# frozen_string_literal: true

## SAMPLE VARIANTS
sizes = %w[small medium large]
colors = %w[red green blue]
materials = %w[cotton linen]

titles = sizes.product(colors, materials).map do |variant|
  variant.join(' - ')
end

p titles
```

Which I think is some nice-looking, easy to read, easy to understand code.